# postgres in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1251"

Tags: postgresql

I use function in postgres `convert_to(_xml, 'WIN1251' )`. It returns the error: '*For a character with a byte sequence 0xc2 0x98 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1251"*'.

- `0xc2 0x98` - this is Cyrillic 'И'
- `_xml` - this is XML string

Comment: Keep using Unicode, not Windows 1251. It's quite likely your programming language only allows Unicode strings anyway - Java, JavaScript, C# (actually all .NET languages), Python 3, all use Unicode strings. This page is Unicode. Almost all web sites (except for some mean-spirited government sites) are Unicode.

Comment: And I'd bet the XML string is Unicode too - while it's possible to use a different encoding, provided it's specified in the `encoding`  attribute of the prolog, it's *extremely* rare to find such documents. All XML serializers default to UTF8